# Acer ES1-411 stuck on boot screen - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, acer-aspire

I have an Acer ES1-411, of a customer, with faulty HDD. I swiped old HDD with a newly bought one, but the Windows installation gets stuck on the boot screen, after first restart. I used a bootable pendrive and that works fine, because I recently used that pendrive in another notebook to install Windows.

The strange thing is, the Windows copied all files to HDD, but after restart, the installation loads a small bit and stops. Maybe the problem is with a driver.

My client says he had Windows 10 installed on this notebook, before the HDD stop working.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: May be consider replacing CMOS battery. How did you identify that there were problems with HDD?

Comment: The Hdd was full of bad blocks, and making strange noises...The CMOS battery can stop a installation?

Comment: I'm just guessing here. There can me many reasons why your Acer behaves like that. Have you performed a clean install (fully formatting the new drive)? Did you properly mount your drive to SATA port? May be you try to install x64 version of Windows when it only makes sense to install x86 on your machine. May be it makes sense to re-mount the Windows image on your pendrive. Are you trying to install from SD card but call it pendrive? Provide more details.

Comment: Yes, the HDD is clean, i did an "low-level format". Yes, mounted correctly. I tried x64 and x86, but stops in the same logo screen. I tried to install from a DVD and a pen drive (not SD card).

Comment: I am in exactly the same situation, and can find no solution. I have the original working HDD, but as soon as I try to install win10 on the replacement SSD, windows crashes on first bootup after install. However if I clone the HDD to the SSD (not ideal as its full of junk) the SSD works fine. Something about the Acer ES1-411 vs win10 install vs SSD :-(

Answer (score 0):

some suggestions:

- unplug from power, remove battery and press shutdown button for 10 seconds holding it. then place battery back + power and try to start pc.
- If you hold the power button down for 10 seconds it will shut the laptop down. Then power it on again and if it gets stuck, do the power button again. After 3 attempts to boot you should get a troubleshoot screen. Under Advanced Options is an Automatic Repair button. Try that and see if it fixes it.
- try to go in Safe Mode.
- maybe dust inside and overheating? for any case,clean it.
- Try removing the RAM. Clean all the contacts with a soft pencil eraser and blow out the slots with a can of compressed air. Then try to start the PC with just one of the sticks, if that fails then try with another stick.
- Have you tried booting from the OS/LIVE disc?
- Disconnect everything from the motherboard except the speaker and take out the RAM sticks - you should hear an error code which you can look up on the Acer website. If No beeps,then the board may be dead.
- reset the BIOS to default by shorting out the appropriate pins on the motherboard (You will need to look at the manual for the machine or motherboard to find which pins these are and how to do it. As a clue the pins are usually near the CMOS battery and there are 3 of them - there will be a jumper in place so it needs to be removed and, with the mains supply disconnected, placed on the other 'pair' for a count of 20 seconds. Restart the machine and go into the BIOS and reset as necessary).
- Try booting with the hard drive disconnect but with the RAM in, tell us what happens.
- The only other suggestion I have is to flash the Bios which may have been corrupted. This would explain the boot up problem, a bad Bios would results in a boot failure. You would need to identify the motherboard first in order to obtain the correct Bios version before doing this. After that I think you have to assume that the motherboard or the CPU has developed a fault.

source: http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/acer-aspire-freezes-on-the-acer-logo-at-startup.166391/

Comment: I already did all these steps. Including update of BIOS, but it stops in exactly same logo screen. I made a fresh install of Windows 7 and works fine, but i need the Windows 10. I'll put a image to better explain.

Comment: Can you enable logging at startup and check where the log file stops?

Answer (score 0):

Acer Aspire ES1-411, be it Windows 8.1 and 10, it freezes on the loading logo of it after the first phase or everything had been copied to the HDD on your manual fresh format. Solution to that was inserting any SD card.

See discussion here: [Acer Aspire freezes on the "Acer" logo at startup](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/acer-aspire-freezes-on-the-acer-logo-at-startup.166391/page-2).

Comment: Can confirm that booting with SD card inserted in legacy mode alows the installation to continue. I suspect it reads the sd card slot as a drive and is waiting for it to be ready.... hence the hang with no card inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution to this is enable it in uefi mode, format it manually with any 64bit windows 8.1 or 10. this way it will not suffer any freeze or hang, even if installing drivers inside the OS.

http://community.acer.com/t5/E-F-and-M-Series-Laptops/my-es1-411-c00k-dos-labtopnever-complete-windows-installation/td-p/372713